# What is the simplest way to display an aligned table from an Array of Strings in a TextBox using just Tabs (not using Tabstops)

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of strings with 5 entries, where each string consists of 7 fields separated by comma's.
Those fields are of different lengths. I'm using a monospace font, so I can align things with tabs.

I had build a loop that goes through the string array, splitting the strings in the array, to determine which string in each "column" is the longest.
Then another loop, where I assemble a string with fields followed by a vbTab, and if the current field is a multiple of 8 shorter than the maximum length I add extra vbTabs (so if it's 8 shorter, add an extra vbTab, 16 = 2 vbTabs, etc).

But I have trouble getting things properly aligned in some cases.

Code:

```
Sub WriteTidyBlockH_layoutissues(list As List(Of String))
        'Takes a list of strings as argument
        'Writes it out as a table
        'Assumes first line is a header (will be bolded)
        'Go through list, split table fields and determine their lengths

        Dim strLineFields As String()   'string array to hold the fields in a single line
        Dim strLineField As String      'an individual field in a line
        Dim FieldMaxLengths As New List(Of Integer)()  'list that will hold max length of each column
        Dim i, j, k, intLines, intColumns As Integer
        Dim strLine As String           'string to build a tabbed line in
        Dim Tabs As Byte
        'determine number of lines
        intLines = list.Count - 1
        'determine number of columns by counting the commas
        intColumns = list(0).Count(Function(c As Char) c = ",")
        For i = 0 To intColumns
            FieldMaxLengths.Add(0)
        Next
        Dim strFields(intLines, intColumns) As String     '2 dimensional array of strings, containing ALL fields

        i = 0
        For Each strListElement As String In list
            j = 0
            strLineFields = Split(strListElement, ",")
            For Each strLineField In strLineFields
                strFields(i, j) = strLineFields(j)
                If strLineFields(j).Length > FieldMaxLengths(j) Then
                    FieldMaxLengths(j) = strLineFields(j).Length
                End If
                j += 1
            Next
            i += 1
        Next
        For i = 0 To intLines
            strLine = ""
            For j = 0 To intColumns
                If Not j = intColumns Then
                    strLine += strFields(i, j) + vbTab 'one tab is always needed for every field, except the last

                    If strFields(i, j).Length <= FieldMaxLengths(j) Then
                        'strLine += strFields(i, j) + vbTab
                        'figure out how many additional tabs necessary
                        Tabs = (FieldMaxLengths(j) - strFields(i, j).Length) \ 8  'Div
                        For k = 1 To Tabs
                            strLine += vbTab
                        Next

                    End If
                Else
                    'last column, don't add tabs
                    strLine += strFields(i, j)
                End If
            Next
            If i = 0 Then
                WriteOut(strLine, 0, True)
            Else
                WriteOut(strLine)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Output currently looks like this:

```
Bank    Location    Capacity    Speed   Manufacturer    Part Number Serial Number
BANK 0  ChannelA-DIMM0  8GB 1600    Kingston    99U5471-066.A00LF   24E8D583
BANK 1  ChannelA-DIMM1  8GB 1600    Kingston    99U5471-054.A00LF   30269BB7
BANK 2  ChannelB-DIMM0  8GB 1600    Kingston    99U5471-058.A00LF   182C9113
BANK 3  ChannelB-DIMM1  8GB 1600    Kingston    99U5471-054.A00LF   D63F4C11
```

N.B. I'm having some trouble with formatting. In the *actual* output, only Capacity and Serial Number are misaligned (too far left), while Spped, Manufacturer and Part Number are correctly aligned with the data under them.

N.B.: WriteOut is just a sub that writes a single string to the textbox and appends a vbCrLf. The other two arguments are optional (color and bold).

Comment: _"But I have trouble getting things properly aligned in some cases"_ If you have a problem _with your code_, you almost always need to include your code [into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58354492/edit). Please read [ask] and how to create a [repro] for more information.

Comment: I had not included my code because I'm postive how I am attempting to do it is not *the simplest way*  :-)

Comment: I included the code

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using a DataGridView/DataGrid?

Comment: Yes. In this application, I will be displaying tons of information. Most of it wil be unformatted text, but some information (like the example with the information on memory banks) is better presented in a table. The application consists of one form, with one button, and one RichTextBox. I don't want to add other controls.

Comment: If you use a fixed-width font for that part of the text, you can do [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?530270) sort of thing.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, that looks promising. I'll give that idea a try! Only on the second reading did I actually notice that this writeup on vbforums was yours :-) Cheers